# strange behavior of 'inverse_transform' function in sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScalar

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I used MinMaxScalar function in sklearn.preprocessing for normalizing the attributes of some of my variables(array) to use that in a model(linear regression), after the model creation and training
I tested my model with `x_test(splited usind train_test_split)` and stored the result in some `variable(say predicted)` ,for evaluating purpose i wanna evaluate my prediction with the original dataset for that i used "`MinMaxScalar.inverse_transform`" function, that function works well when my code is in below order,

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,train_size=0.75,random_state=27)

sc=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
y_train=y_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train=sc.fit_transform(y_train)
```

> when i changed the order like the below code it throws me error
> on-broadcastable output operand with shape (379,1) doesn't match the
> broadcast shape (379,13))

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.25,train_size=0.75,random_state=27)

sc=MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
y_train=y_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train=sc.fit_transform(y_train)
x_test=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
```

please compare the two photos for better understanding of my query:

[image: please compare the two photos for better understanding of my query]

Answer (score 1):

It can be seen from the linked printscreen figure that you use the *same* `MinMaxScaler` to *fit* and *transform* both the train and test x-data, and also the training y-data (which does not make sense).

The correct process would be

1. Fit the scaler with train x-data. The `fit_transform()` also transforms (scales) the `x_train`.

```py
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train = sc.fit_transform(x_train)
```

2. Scale also the test x-data with the *same* scaler. Do not `fit` here; just scale/transform.

```py
x_test = sc.transform(x_test)
```

3. *If* you think scaling is needed also for y-data, you will have to fit *another* scaler for that purpose. It could also be that there is no need for scaling the y-data.

```py
# Option A: Do not scale y-data
# (do nothing)

# Option B: Scale y-data
sc_y = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
y_train = sc_y.fit_transform(y_train)
```

4. After you have trained your model (`lr`), you can make predictions with the scaled `x_test` and the model:

```py
# Option A:
predicted = lr.predict(x_test)

# Option B:
y_test_scaled = lr.predict(x_test)
predicted = sc_y.inverse_transform(y_test_scaled)
```